# Why does my second python async (scraping) function (which uses results from the first async (scraping) function) return no result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

### Summary of what the program should do:

Step 1 (sync): Determine exactly how many pages need to be scraped.

Step 2 (sync): create the links to the pages to be scraped in a for-loop.

Step 3 (async): Use the link list from step 2 to get the links to the desired detail pages from each of these pages.

Step 4 (async): Use the result from step 3 to extract the detail information for each hofladen. This information is stored in a list for each farm store and each of these lists is appended to a global list.

### Where do I have the problem?

The transition from step 3 to step 4 does not seem to work properly.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/PycharmProjects/PKI-Projekt/test_ttt.py", line 108, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/miniconda3/envs/scrapy/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/miniconda3/envs/scrapy/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/PycharmProjects/PKI-Projekt/test_ttt.py", line 96, in main
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks_detail_infos)
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/PycharmProjects/PKI-Projekt/test_ttt.py", line 61, in scrape_detail_infos
    data = JsonLdExtractor().extract(body_d)
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/miniconda3/envs/scrapy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/extruct/jsonld.py", line 21, in extract
    tree = parse_html(htmlstring, encoding=encoding)
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/miniconda3/envs/scrapy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/extruct/utils.py", line 10, in parse_html
    return lxml.html.fromstring(html, parser=parser)
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/miniconda3/envs/scrapy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 873, in fromstring
    doc = document_fromstring(html, parser=parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/miniconda3/envs/scrapy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 761, in document_fromstring
    raise etree.ParserError(
lxml.etree.ParserError: Document is empty

Process finished with exit code 1
```

### What did I do to isolate the problem?

In a first attempt I rewrote the async function append_detail_infos so that it no longer tries to create a list and append the values but only prints data[0]["name"].
This resulted in the error message

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/PycharmProjects/PKI-Projekt/test_ttt.py", line 108, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/miniconda3/envs/scrapy/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/miniconda3/envs/scrapy/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/PycharmProjects/PKI-Projekt/test_ttt.py", line 96, in main
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks_detail_infos)
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/PycharmProjects/PKI-Projekt/test_ttt.py", line 61, in scrape_detail_infos
    data = JsonLdExtractor().extract(body_d)
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/miniconda3/envs/scrapy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/extruct/jsonld.py", line 21, in extract
    tree = parse_html(htmlstring, encoding=encoding)
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/miniconda3/envs/scrapy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/extruct/utils.py", line 10, in parse_html
    return lxml.html.fromstring(html, parser=parser)
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/miniconda3/envs/scrapy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 873, in fromstring
    doc = document_fromstring(html, parser=parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "/Users/REPLACED_MY_USER/miniconda3/envs/scrapy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 761, in document_fromstring
    raise etree.ParserError(
lxml.etree.ParserError: Document is empty

Process finished with exit code 1
```

In the next attempt, I exported the links from detail_links as .csv and visually checked them and opened some of them to see if they were valid. This was also the case.

### The program code:

```py
import asyncio
import time
import aiohttp
import requests
import re
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser
from extruct.jsonld import JsonLdExtractor
import pandas as pd

BASE_URL = "https://hofladen.info"
FIRST_PAGE = 1


def get_last_page(url: str) -> int:
    res = requests.get(url).text
    html = HTMLParser(res)
    last_page = int(re.findall("(\d+)", html.css("li.page-last > a")[0].attributes["href"])[0])

    return last_page


def build_links_to_pages(start: int, ende: int) -> list:
    lst = []
    for i in range(start, ende + 1):
        url = f"https://hofladen.info/regionale-produkte?page={i}"
        lst.append(url)

    return lst


async def scrape_detail_links(url: str):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, allow_redirects=True) as resp:
            body = await resp.text()
            html = HTMLParser(body)

            for node in html.css(".sp13"):
                detail_link = BASE_URL + node.attributes["href"]
                detail_links.append(detail_link)


async def append_detail_infos(data):
    my_detail_lst = []
    # print(data[0]["name"])  # name for debugging purpose
    my_detail_lst.append(data[0]["name"])  # name
    my_detail_lst.append(data[0]["address"]["streetAddress"])  # str
    my_detail_lst.append(data[0]["address"]["postalCode"])  # plz
    my_detail_lst.append(data[0]["address"]["addressLocality"])  # ort
    my_detail_lst.append(data[0]["address"]["addressRegion"])  # bundesland
    my_detail_lst.append(data[0]["address"]["addressCountry"])  # land
    my_detail_lst.append(data[0]["geo"]["latitude"])  # breitengrad
    my_detail_lst.append(data[0]["geo"]["longitude"])  # längengrad

    detail_infos.append(my_detail_lst)


async def scrape_detail_infos(detail_link: str):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session_detailinfos:
        async with session_detailinfos.get(detail_link) as res_d:
            body_d = await res_d.text()
            data = JsonLdExtractor().extract(body_d)
            await append_detail_infos(data)


async def main() -> None:
    start_time = time.perf_counter()

    # Beginn individueller code
    # ----------
    global detail_links, detail_infos
    detail_links, detail_infos = [], []

    tasks = []
    tasks_detail_infos = []
    # extrahiere die letzte zu iterierende Seite
    last_page = get_last_page("https://hofladen.info/regionale-produkte")

    # scrape detail links
    links_to_pages = build_links_to_pages(FIRST_PAGE, last_page)
    for link in links_to_pages:
        task = asyncio.create_task(scrape_detail_links(link))
        tasks.append(task)



    print("Saving the output of extracted information.")
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    pd.DataFrame(data=detail_links).to_csv("detail_links.csv")

    # scrape detail infos
    for detail_url in detail_links:
        task_detail_infos = asyncio.create_task(scrape_detail_infos(detail_url))
        tasks_detail_infos.append(task_detail_infos)

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks_detail_infos)

    # Ende individueller Code
    # ------------

    time_difference = time.perf_counter() - start_time
    print(f"Scraping time: {time_difference} seconds.")
    print(len(detail_links))
    # print(detail_infos[])



asyncio.run(main())
```

### A working solution to the problem:

added `python allow_redirects=True` to `python async with session_detailinfos.get(detail_link, allow_redirects=True) as res_d:`

added `python return_exceptions=True` to `python await asyncio.gather(*tasks_detail_infos, return_exceptions=True)`

Comment: Your attempt to `print` some of that info was futile because your program did not even get to the `append_detail_infos` function. The error occurred (as evidenced by the traceback) when calling the `extract` method of the `JsonLdExtractor` and the message seems pretty clear to me: `Document is empty`. So I would suggest checking, what you actually receive back from the server by adding `print(res_d.status)` and `print(body_d)` right before that `extract` call.

Comment: In addition, you may want to restrict yourself to a single page while testing to make debugging (as I suggested above) easier. You can easily do that e.g. by writing `for detail_url in detail_links[:1]` to only create a single task.

Comment: Also, checking the URLs you say you are parsing - which are like: "https://hofladen.info/regionale-produkte?page=3" actually gets a redirect response to another page. The final URL is likely incorrect -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A working solution to the problem:

added
`python allow_redirects=True` to `python async with session_detailinfos.get(detail_link, allow_redirects=True) as res_d:`

added `python return_exceptions=True` to `python await asyncio.gather(*tasks_detail_infos, return_exceptions=True)`